# Find out what program runs in the java.exe process

Tags: windows, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out what program runs in the java.exe process](https://superuser.com/questions/212296/find-out-what-program-runs-in-the-java-exe-process)

Hi! 
I have posted this question in stackoverflow.com and I was told this would be a best place to ask, so here I am :).

I have a problem: always when my computer starts, there is a java.exe process listening in the port 7676. I want to find out what it is to be able to delete it.

Is there any way that I can find that out? I have seen another question here which lead me to download the Sysinternal's Process Explorer, but it didn't help me :(

Is there any way to find that out?

thanks, 
Oscar

Comment: Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/212296/find-out-what-program-runs-in-the-java-exe-process

Answer (score 0):

Try Microsoft's Process Explorer:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Looking for port 7676 indicates that it may be used for a Message Queue broker. Do you have an iMQ message broker installed?

Comment: I have more than one, this is exactly the issue...