# Find out what program runs in the java.exe process

Tags: windows, java, process, port

I have a problem: always when my computer starts, there is a `java.exe` process listening in the port 7676. I want to find out what it is to be able to delete it.

Is there any way that I can find that out?

I have seen another question here which lead me to download the Sysinternal's Process Explorer, but it didn't help me...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [Sysinternal's Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). Like task manager, this application can show you all running processes.

But it can also show you the command line arguments used to launch the process: right click the column headers and select the "command line" column. This extra information will help you identify which java application is running in a given `java.exe` process.

If that is not yet enough information, Process Explorer can also tell you which files, network connections, registry entries etc. are being used by the process.

**update**: as mentioned in the comments below, the standard Windows Task Manager can also show the command line. Go to "View" - "Select Columns..." and check "Command Line".

Comment: You can also view the command line in the default Windows task manager

Comment: @starofale: I can't find that option in the Windows XP task manager. Perhaps it was added in Vista or Windows 7.

Comment: Oh, that's possible - I don't have a copy of XP to check with

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to find the process id using `netstat`. You [can use `wmic` after that](http://mattejones.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/using-wmic-to-get-process-information/).

```
wmic process where processid=<pid> get commandline
```

This should give you more details about the Java process in case you're running it on Windows.

Since this is an extremely old thread, could you tell me what was the final solution that you used?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to find the process id using `netstat -o`.

You can then get information on this process by running `jps -v`. This works like the Unix `ps`.

If you want to see more details about the application you can run up `JConsole` for the Java process and then look for a thread listening on the port.

Comment: These tools are not part of the JRE. `jps` and `jconsole` are only available if you have the java development kit (JDK) installed, which is usually not the case for an end user.